# Pass arguments to react-admin dataProvider getList

Tags: react-admin

How can I pass additional arguments from the `List` component to the dataProvider I am building?

For example:

```
<List filter={myFilters} perPage={10} myArgs={someArgs} {...props} >
```

I do receive the `filter` argument, but I don't receive `myArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `dataProvider.getList()` only accepts filter, sort, and pagination parameters (see [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#request-format)).

You can add code in your dataProvider to transform a specific filter into a special argument, or use another resource name that triggers a special piece of logic.

But the question is: why do you need to pass additional parameters for?

Comment: I want to add url query parameters to the http requests. I'm piggybacking the filter argument for now, but this is ugly AF.